# Azure Application Insights traces not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, blazor, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure Logging for my .NET 6 Blazor server application. In the past it has not been an issue for me, but now I can not see any Traces logs on Azure. I have been followring these qusetions:

[Application Insights' Logs Not Writing to Traces Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052823/application-insights-logs-not-writing-to-traces-log)

[ILogger Logging Doesn't Show Up in Azure Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353327/ilogger-logging-doesnt-show-up-in-azure-application-insights?rq=1)

Moreover I have followed the documentation here:

[Application Insights logging with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger)

[Application Insights for ASP.NET Core applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#prerequisites)

[Migrate from Application Insights instrumentation keys to connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings#new-capabilities)

[Sampling in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling)

**The code**

*AppSettings*

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },

"ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "
InstrumentationKey=Here i put the InstrumentationKey ofc. ;IngestionEndpoint=https://northeurope2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/
;LiveEndpoint=https://northeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  },
```

*Program.cs*

```
var options = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions { ConnectionString = configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"] };
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);
```

*The razor.cs page*

```
    [Inject]
    public ILogger<NailOtherSingelShearTimberTimber> Logger { get; set; }

    public async Task SaveFile()
    {
        Logger.LogWarning("File saved");       
    }
```

If i run it locally I can see it is being sent...

[image]

But I get nothing on Azure no matter how long i wait.

[image]

And Data sampling is set to 100%

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting the AdaptiveSampling property to false. It is on by default.

Comment: Refer [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804024/insert-binary-file-into-mssql-db-varbinary-with-python-pymssql)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnandSowmithiran. Unfortunately that did not help either.

Comment: Traces and Exceptions are two different things. For me it was the other way around. Exceptions did not show up but traces did. [This](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-send-an-exception-to-application-insights-in-net-33fa15ad0887) article helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days without any success I decided to delete the web app + resource group and created a new web app. Then I updated the connection string in AppSettings, published the application and now logging works like a charm.

Comment: Yep, apparently this is one of the solutions, I was getting requests details in the Overview page of Application Insights, but when querying the actual Requests table it was empty, deleting and recreating the resource worked for me